# Extend icon theme with extension Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to extend an icon set with your extension? If so, how can I add this to my language extension?

I have an extension for our custom language, and I'd like to include icons for the supported file types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not supported. There's an open feature request here:

[#14662 - [file icons] Support for extending the file icon theme from an extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14662)

#### Update on Jan 3, 2022

[#140047 - [api] finalize icon property of the language contribution point](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140047)

Api has been finalised to use a png or svg icon in the language definition.

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "latex",
        // ...
        "icon": {
          "light": "./icons/latex-light.png",
          "dark": "./icons/latex-dark.png"
        }
      }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Supported as of v1.64, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70930298/836330 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#language-default-icons