# adding a language-specific icon in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a language extension (syntax highlighting, etc) and now want to associated a specific icon with the language (or files with the extensions specified in my extension).

I noticed an `"icon"` property is available in the `package.json` file, and tried to bind this property to my `.svg` file. But while syntax highlighting works just fine on a test file, I don't see my custom icon associated with this file.

Where do I add a reference to my `.svg` file?  Do I have to somehow contribute my `.svg` file to the Seti File Icon Theme?

Answer (score 7):

In vscode v1.64:

> ##### Language default icons
>
> Language contributors can define an icon for the language.

```json
"contributes": {  
     "languages": [
       {
         "id": "latex",
         // ...
         "icon": {
           "light": "./icons/latex-light.png",
           "dark": "./icons/latex-dark.png"
         }
       }
   ] 
}
```

The icon is shown if the current file icon theme only has a generic file icon for the language.

> File icon themes like Minimal or None that do not show file icons also
> will not use the language icon. Also, if a file icon theme has an icon
> for an extension or file name, these will be preferred.
>
> File icon themes can customize the new behavior by defining
> `showLanguageModeIcons: true|false` in the theme file.
>
> `showLanguageModeIcons: true` shows the default language icons even if
> the theme does not specify a file icon
> `showLanguageModeIcons: false` prevents that default language icons are used.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#language-default-icons

Answer (score 2):

File and folder icons are [defined in icon sets](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes), the default set being Seti. There is indeed currently no way to re-define those icons in an extension, short of [creating your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_adding-a-new-icon-theme) icon theme. The Seti UI icons are [generated from a dependency](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/67b561235327d7e5f008229f978bcf3e6abcad18/extensions/theme-seti/icons) to the [main repo](https://github.com/jesseweed/seti-ui) and shipped as a built-in extension.

Therefore, your best bet to get your syntax icon included in VScode is submitting a pull request to the Seti UI repository. At some point, the new icons will be rolled into an icon font by the VScode developers and your icons should appear.

Comment: This answer is out of date as of v1.64. See Mark's answer.

Answer (score -1):

!!

UPDATED: see other comments to proper answer

There is newer version of vscode. So no need for this 'hack' anymore.

!!

Unfortunately you have to specify whole theme icon specification in current version of vscode.

There is PR on github that should allow extend default icons: [Support extending icon themes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110830)

Before it will be merged and included into new version there is possibility to copy default `seti` configuration

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-seti/icons/seti.woff
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-seti/icons/vs-seti-icon-theme.json

and add your own icon into vs-seti-icon-theme.json config according doc [File Icon Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme)

Comment: This answer is out of date as of v1.64. See Mark's answer.